# Non-minimum phase systems

Tags: control-theory

I wanted to clear this doubt I have since a long time and for which I am not able to find a clear answer since different sources say differently or ambiguously.

$\textbf{Does a system have to be stable to be minimum phase?}$ By definition, does a minimum phase system require stability or just Left Half Plane zeros?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The above is one definition. An alternative definition, also used in the literature, is that a continuous-time transfer function is stable if the poles have negative real part, and minimum-phase if the zeros have negative real part. With the latter definition, the concepts of stability and minimum-phase are independent. It's a question of taste, which one to adopt.

Comment: Yeah that may be true but I think there has to be one definition...as far as definitions go shouldn't there be a clear and unambiguous one...this confusion defeats the point of it being a definition

Comment: That is a nice thought and wish, however both definitions can be found, and it is not easy to persuade people to switch over.

Stable allpass filters increase the phase, in the sense of making it more negative in all frequencies, so the definition of minimum-phase with respect to the zeros only fits better with the word minimum. Still, it's a matter of taste.

Comment: yup...that is true...thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

A minimum-phase system should NOT have any poles or zeros in the open right half of s-plane. This effectively imply that the minimum-phase system has to be at least Lyapunov stable if not asymptotically stable.

Comment: this is what I have read in most places but different elsewhere...I have seen people adopt different approaches too...is there no final word on it?

Comment: No, different definitions appear in different texts that are widely read. I guess the definition of minimum phase with respect to zeros only is more common but the one in this answer is also used.